# Scope of objects created inside a function - Will they be valid if references are stored and accessed outside the function?

Tags: c++, vector

The following code works. But i am not sure if it is really OK to write it this way.

```
class A {
private:
   struct packet {
       string header;
       string data;
   }
   vector<packet > packets;

public:
   void add_packet(string h, string d) {
      struct packet p1;   // Isnt this variable on stack and will be destroyed at the end of the function?
      p1.header = h;
      p1.data = d;
      packets.push_back(p1);  // Is it ok to add the variable on stack to a member variable?
   }

   void print_packets() {
      // Iterates over the packets and prints header and data
   }
}
```

`void push_back (const value_type& val);` is the prototype of push_back. So, i believe the packets vector only stores the reference of the variable(which is on stack). My question is after `add_packet(h, d)`  returns, will the references stored in the vector still be valid?

Comment: The `vector` contains `packet` _values_. Containers can't contain references in C++. `push_back()` has overloads for `const&` and `&&` to enable `move()`ing in an rvalue, but `const&` doesn't mean it saves a ref, just that it won't copy >once, as pass-by-value would. It is very common to take by `const&` then copy, whether or not accompanied by anoverload to enable moving. Only if the recipient contains a reference (or wrapper, or pointer) is one taken. Any decent doc explains that `push_back(const&)` copies, eg  [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back) does

Comment: `struct packet p1;` is a C-ism. In C++ you don't need the `struct` bit, simply `packet p1;` is fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot judge what a function will do with a parameter just by it's signature.  Even though you are calling

```
void push_back (const value_type& val);
```

`push_back` is actually going to make a copy of `val` and store that copy in the vector.  This means there is no dangling reference.

Answer (score 4):

`push_back()` stores a *copy* of what you pass to it. The source object is free to die afterwards, that won't affect the copy in the `std::vector`.